# Should Observers be notified in separate threads each one?

Tags: multithreading, observer-pattern

I know it sounds heavy weight, but I'm trying to solve an hypothetical situation. Imagine you have *N* observers of some object. Each one interested in the object state. When applying the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) the *observable* object tends to iterate through its observer list invoking the observer `notify()|update()` method.

Now imagine that a specific observer has a lot of work to do with the state of the *observable* object. That will slow down the last notification, for example.

So, in order to avoid slowing down notifications to all observers, one thing we can do is to notify the observer in a separate thread. In order for that to work, I suppose that a thread for each observer is needed. That is a painful overhead we are having in order to avoid the notification slow down caused by heavy work. Worst than slowing down if thread approach is used, is dead threads caused by infinite loops. It would be great reading experienced programmers for this one.

- What people with years on design issues think?
- Is this a problem without a substancial solution?
- Is it a really bad idea? why?

### Example

This is a vague example in order to demonstrate and, hopefully, clarify the basic idea that I don't even tested:

```
class Observable(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.queues = {}

    def addObserver(self, observer):
        if not observer in self.queues:
            self.queues[observer] = Queue()
            ot = ObserverThread(observer, self.queues[observer])
            ot.start()

    def removeObserver(self, observer):
        if observer in self.queues:
            self.queues[observer].put('die')
            del self.queues[observer]

    def notifyObservers(self, state):
        for queue in self.queues.values():
            queue.put(state)

class ObserverThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, observer, queue):
        self.observer = observer
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        running = True
        while running:
            state = self.queue.get()
            if state == 'die':
                running = False
            else:
                self.observer.stateChanged(state)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're on the right track.

It is common for each observer to own its own input-queue and its own message handling thread (or better: the queue would own the thread, and the observer would own the queue). See [Active object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_object).

There are some pitfalls however:

- If you have 100's or 1000's of observers you may need to use a [thread pool pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern)
- Note the you'll lose control over the order in which events are going to be processed (which observer handles the event first). This may be a non-issue, or may open a Pandora box of very-hard-to-detect bugs. It depends on your specific application.
- You may have to deal with situations where observers are deleted before notifiers. This can be somewhat tricky to handle correctly.
- You'll need to implement messages instead of calling functions. Message generation may require more resources, as you may need to allocate memory, copy objects, etc. You may even want to optimize by implementing a message pool for common message types (you may as well choose to implement a message factory that wrap such pools).
- To further optimize, you'll probably like to generate one message and send it to all to observers (instead of generating many copies of the same message). You may need to use some [reference counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) mechanism for your messages.

Comment: wouldn't it be better that Observable just notifies the Observers and leaves it to them to take actions when they feel appropriate?

Comment: @NarendraPathai: This leads to a more complex pattern: each observer would have to implement one methods to be informed about the event, and another method to handle the event (in its own internal thread). Moreover, even deciding in the event is important may require considerable resources in some situations.

Comment: @LiorKogan in my case, the order in which observer processes notifications first is not important. However, it must be guaranteed that observers receives changes in the same order than the observable has changed in time and they must not miss any change. One question though: if every observer has its thread where they sequentially processes notifications, why avoid calling observer methods and use messages instead?

Comment: @Sebastian: Of course you'll have to call observer methods, but you'll need to pass parameters for these methods. A message is exactly a block of parameters that may be queued. The number of message types equals to the number of methods that you'll have to call. it is simpler if there is only one method, as seems to be your case: state-changed method, but consider the case where there are several message-types / methods for example: EventAHappened, EventBHappened, etc. - each event has its own set of parameters.

Comment: @LiorKogan I think that a better and extensible approach is to avoid creating different methods for different message type. A broadcast of the message should be made and each observer should know what to do with it. If you end in writting custom methods for custom messages, you'll end in a complex maintained code needed to change for new kind of messages. With only one notification method, you don't need to know how the messages will be processed by the observer, neither add method calls.

Comment: @Sebastian: In my use case, there were 100's of message types, each has its own set of parameters. I observed 10's of sensor of different types, that generates many event types, and I need to notify 10's of observers: logic classes, loggers, views, etc. Your use case may be simpler.

Comment: @LiorKogan I see your point, despite use cases, If I understand correctly your design, I was trying to introduce the [Single Responsability Principle](http://tinyurl.com/5hw7su). If you add one new sensor,you probably would have a new message type.That implies a new message event.So instead of notifying with `update()` all your observers, you'll need to add the new `newSensorEvent()` to each of your observers, and *change* your observable object (by adding the call to `newSensorEvent()` on the observer). That is, your observable now depends on the message type and the observers objects.

Comment: @Sebastian: I'm not a big fan of the Single Responsibility Principle. A class that calculates expected stock prices or probability for an earthquake would change based on 100's of reasons. Each such reason is manifested as a different msg.type (with different parameters). I implemented a registration mechanism. Each observer registers only to msgs it has interest in. This is in line with the [Interface segregation principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle). All my msgs inherits from the same base class, so new msgs requires changes only in interested observers.

Comment: The good thing about stackoverflow is this gratificant discussion we also could make in comments. This answer is useful to me, as much as the comments we shared. @LiorKogan best regards, and thanks for sharing knowledge on me.

Answer (score 2):

Let each observer decide itself if its reaction is heavyweight, and if so, start a thread, or submit a task to a thread pool. Making notification in a separate thread is not a good solution: while freeing the observable object, it limits the processor power for notifications with single thread. If you do not trust your observers, then create a thread pool and  for each notification, create a task and submit it to the pool.

Comment: I see, but, what if the observer just can't know how long will it take to process the update?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion when you have a **large no** of Observers for an Observable, which do heavy processing, then the best thing to do is to have a `notify()` method in Observer.

Use of `notify()`: Just to set the `dirty` flag in the `Observer` to `true`. So whenever the Observer thread will find it appropriate it will **query** the Observable for the required updates.

And this would not require heavy processing on `Observable` side and **shift the load** to the `Observer` side.

Now it depends on the `Observers` when they have to Observe.

Comment: @Narenda I think that the main problem with this approach is that observers could lost some changes in the observable object, as instead of receiving a "snapshot" of the change the observer is informed that a change has been made, and eventually will query the object state. So, when the observer makes the query the observable object could have changed again. The result is a change in the object we have lost.

Comment: @Sebastian after your argument I feel that it depends on the type of application(whether each snapshot is critical or not). In case of RSS reader I think my solution should be better!

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Pathai is valid in a lot of cases.

One is that you are observing changes in a database. In many ways you can't reconstruct the final state from the snapshots alone, especially if your state is fetched as a complex query from the database, and the snapshot is an update to the database.

To implement it, I'd suggest using an Event object:

```
class Observer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.event = threading.Event()

# in observer:
while self.event.wait():
    # do something
    self.event.clear()

# in observable:
observer.event.set()
```